# Duration of inflationary epoch

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Why is it thought that the inflationary epoch of the universe lasted approximately $10^{-30}$ seconds and why did it take the inflaton (assuming its existence) to release the energy contained itself that exact amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question of how long it takes inflation to release energy. It's a matter of the energy scale of inflation and the requirement that it last long enough to solve the [horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem) and [flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem) problems.

The Hubble rate during inflation is $H=\sqrt{8\pi G\rho/3}$, where $\rho$ is the inflaton's (constant) energy density. Inflation needs to last at least 60 Hubble times $H^{-1}$ (corresponding to the Universe growing by $\rm{e}^{60}$) in order to solve the horizon and flatness problems, though it could have lasted much longer.

In units where $c=\hbar=1$, the gravitational constant is $G=m_\rm{p}^{-2}$, where $m_\rm{p}$ is the Planck mass. The energy scale of inflation is typically expected to be around $10^{-6}m_\mathrm{p}$ (e.g. [Liddle 1994](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9307020)), so $\rho\sim (10^{-6}m_\rm{p})^4\sim 10^{-24}m_\rm{p}^4$, and hence $H\sim 10^{-12}m_\rm{p}$. But in these units, $m_\rm{p}^{-1}\sim 10^{-43}\rm{s}$ (the Planck time), so $H^{-1}\sim 10^{12}m_\rm{p}^{-1}\sim10^{-31}\rm{s}$, and again, the duration of inflation should be at least 60 times that.